# ScrollView issue on AutoLayout ( Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, size-classes

I'm trying to create a registration form for my application.

After droping all desire textfields on scrollView, I have setup its all desire constraints and i'm using "Any H" and "Any W" for Size Class.

on Storyboard its showing warning for textField width, when i ran this on device it shrink the textfield, see below images

[image]

Please Help me.

Comment: What constraints do you have on the textfield?

Comment: you can see on above image, for first field i have set top, leading and trailing and bottom/vertical with next below field

Comment: It's look like you're missing an height or width constraint from your screenshot. How I solve those problems : I think that I am Interface Builder, and I draw my view on a paper, just reading constraints, you Will find missing constraints obvious doing that.

Comment: i can't fix the width of textField as i mention i'm using Xcode 6 with Size Class(Any H Any W).

Comment: yes i can fixed the height of all textFields

Comment: add textfield to scroll view with horizontaly centre in container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your textfield to scrollview with "horizontal centre in container". That means how much your scrollview width is increase/decrease your textfield will remain in centre with its leading and trailing constraint constant. So it will adjust its width as per scrollview width.